# Probability of Repeated Encrypted Block In Output Feedback (OFB) Mode

Tags: ofb

Is there any probability/chances of repeated encrypted block in Output Feedback (OFB) mode?
Is there any existing documentation/studies about that? If it is existing, can you please provide me a link for that documentation, I want to analyze it carefully, I can't find some documentation about the probability of repeated encrypted block in OFB, maybe it is existing but it is hard to find.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if the block cipher is modeled as a random $N$ bit permutation (that is, each permutation from the set of $2^N$ bit patterns to itself is equally probable), then the answer is really quite easy (and this answer is exact): the probability that we will repeat a block within $M$ outputs is precisely $(M-1) 2^{-N}$ (for $0 < M \le 2^N+1$).

The reasoning behind this is remarkably simple.  First, when we consider the sequence $X, P(X), P(P((X)) = P^2(X), P^3(X), ...$, we see that the first pair of repeated elements must include the starting point $X$.  Here's why: if we have the pair $P^i(X) = P^j(X)$ for $i, j \ne 0$, then we have $P^{i-1}(X) = P^{j-1}(X)$ (remember, $P$ is a permutation, that is, if $P(A)=P(B)$, then $A=B$), and so if we have a pair $i,j \ne 0$, that can't be the first pair.

Now, let us compute the conditional probability that, if we haven't had a repeat after $M-1$ outputs, we get a repeat after $M$ outputs.  Now, after we have cycled through $M-1$ outputs, there are $2^N - (M-1)$ outputs we haven't generated before and $1$ output that we have that might be generated in the next step (the other outputs we have generated are impossible, by the reasoning in the above paragraph).  If we've specified $(M-1)$ outputs of a permutation, the rest of the possible outputs are equiprobable, and hence the probability that we're generate the one output that would generate a repeat is $1 / (1 + 2^N - (M-1)) = 1/( 2^N-M)$

Now, the probability that we'll generate the first repeat at step $M$ is the probability that we'll not generate a repeat after $M-1$ steps, and then repeat at step $M$.  This is:

$Prob(M) = (2^N-1)/2^N \cdot (2^N-2)/(2^N-1) \cdot ... \cdot (2^N-M) / (2^N-M+1) \cdot 1 / (2^N-M) = 1/2^N$

That is, the probability that we'll get a repeat after exactly $M$ steps is independent of the value of $M$ (as long as it is in range).

And hence, the probability we'll get a repeat after $M$ steps (or earlier) is just the sum of the probabilities that we'll generate the first repeat after $k$ steps for $1 < k \le M$, and that's $(M-1)/2^N$.

If you insist on a link, you can look at [this one](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_permutation_statistics#Probability_that_a_random_element_lies_on_a_cycle_of_size_m); this uses different logic to come up with the same result.

If the block cipher cannot be modeled as a random permutation (or a random even permutation; that answer differs only in the $M=2^N$ case), well, I don't know on any specific study; that would probably depend on the specific block cipher, and how it differs from a random permutation.

Comment: Nice answer, although I did understand the question a bit different ("what is the probability that ciphertext blocks repeat", which is harder, as it depends on the plaintext) - but your interpretation makes more sense.